# Plotting data channels dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib, signal-processing

I am selecting a list of channels I want to plot from my eeg data (this example is for plotting from a file but this will be expanded to real time streaming too). I pass them into my plotting function by turning the names of the omitted channels to "0", the sensors list would then look something like this:

```
['FT7', '0', '0', 'O2', 'FC4', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I am trying to plot those channels that are named in the list and ignore those listed as 0, but I am struggling to fully plot the data dynamically.
I either get it to plot those selected channels data and those that are marked for skipping are filled with the final index in the list like :[plots last index on "0"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l7T4.png)
Or it will leave the ignored channels blank and then leave ugly gaps where the indexes are "0" like:[gaps on "0"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVjmg.png)

I would like it to dynamically shift the length of the loop to match the number of non-zero indexes but I cannot get it right. I am pretty new to python so this is probably really inefficient but my team and I are doing our best to develop this properly.

When i get it to skip the 0's but it instead plots the last index:

```
if "Time" in plots:
        print("Computing Time Series...")
        fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
        axs_for_plot = []
        for ic, channel_name in enumerate(sensors_to_plot):
            ax = fig.add_subplot(N, 1, 1 + ic)
            chan_idx = index_lookup[channel_name]
            ax.set_title("Sensor {}/{}".format(chan_idx, channel_name))
            pl = ax.plot(timestamps - timestamps[18], eeg[:, chan_idx])
            if ic == N // 2:
                ax.set_ylabel("Voltage (uV)")
            axs_for_plot.append([ax, chan_idx, pl[0]])
        ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
        bprev = Button(plt.axes([0.025, 0.05, 0.05, 0.9]), "<")
        bnext = Button(plt.axes([0.925, 0.05, 0.05, 0.9]), ">")
        win_len = TextBox(
            plt.axes([0.45, 0.95, 0.05, 0.03]), "Window Length (s)", "5", label_pad=0.05
        )

        callback = Index(axs_for_plot)
        bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev_win)
        bnext.on_clicked(callback.next_win)
        win_len.on_text_change(callback.change_w_len)
        callback.update_plots()
        plt.show()
```

When I get it to ignore the 0's but leave gaps:

```
if "Time" in plots:
        print("Computing Time Series...")
        fig = plt.figure(facecolor=(1, 1, 1))
        axs_for_plot = []
        for ic, channel_name in enumerate(sensors_to_plot):
            if channel_name =="0":
                continue
            else:
                ax = fig.add_subplot(N, 1, 1 + ic)
                chan_idx = index_lookup[channel_name]
                ax.set_title("Sensor {}/{}".format(chan_idx, channel_name))
                pl = ax.plot(timestamps - timestamps[18], eeg[:, chan_idx])
                if ic == N // 2:
                    ax.set_ylabel("Voltage (uV)")
                axs_for_plot.append([ax, chan_idx, pl[0]])
        ax.set_xlabel("Time (s)")
        bprev = Button(plt.axes([0.025, 0.05, 0.05, 0.9]), "<")
        bnext = Button(plt.axes([0.925, 0.05, 0.05, 0.9]), ">")
        win_len = TextBox(
            plt.axes([0.45, 0.95, 0.05, 0.03]), "Window Length (s)", "5", label_pad=0.05
        )

        callback = Index(axs_for_plot)
        bprev.on_clicked(callback.prev_win)
        bnext.on_clicked(callback.next_win)
        win_len.on_text_change(callback.change_w_len)
        callback.update_plots()
        plt.show()
```

I should also note that the sensors are joined together on "*" so it passes them in something like this

```
FT7*Fpz*0*O2*0*0*AF8*0*0*0*0*Fz*0*0*0*0
```

and then splits again on the *. Probably not the best way to handle the argv's but it's the simplest way I could get them to make it into the plotting without mixing up the argv's

Note: I can get this to plot well with all channels selected but there is a desire to flexibly choose which channels we want to analyze.
Example of time-series plotting:[Time-domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKY9h.png)
Example of PSD:[PSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plgah.png)
Example of FFT:[FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7agRj.png)
So this code does work when passed all variables I just need to dynamically resize the loop but I am stuck on it.

Comment: Hello to stackoverflow. I suggest creating [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Remove all not necessary stuff, keep only what is relevant to the question and your problem. And make it reproducible, with some example (can be fake, generated) data. In my experience, you will get 10x more support if you *help others help you* in such a way.

Comment: I'll try to get a good minimal example but there are some functions in there that I don't think I can share, so I'll try to preserve the intention while not sharing code that's not mine to share.

Comment: You are welcome to post your solution as an answer, but your question should remain strictly a question. Your edits are preserved in the [edit history.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77303183/revisions)